# Consuming PHP web service by WCF client

Tags: c#, php, wcf, web-services, httpwebrequest

I have a problem in consuming PHP web service by WCF. First, I try to make a proxy class by 'Add service reference' but this don't work:

[image]

Full error message:

```
There was an error downloading 'http://xxx.yyy.zzz.pl/Swdsoapserver/query?wsdl/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
The request failed with the error message:
--
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>Sender</faultcode><faultstring>Invalid XML</faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

--.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://xxx.yyy.zzz.pl/Swdsoapserver/query?wsdl'.
The content type text/html; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:tns="http://xxx.yyy.zzz.pl/Swdsoapserver/query" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap-enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="SwdQuerySoap"
    targetNamespace="http://xxx.yyy.zzz.pl/Swdsoapserver/query">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema
```

I talk with person, that hosting this web service in php, and he says me, that he consume this web service in something like this:

```
$Http = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http();
       $client = new SoapClient("http://".$Http->getServer('HTTP_HOST')."/Swdsoapserver/queryko?wsdl", array        ('trace'         => true));
       $object->sy = "12345678";
       $client->getParcel($object, base64_encode('xyzxyz'));
```

This base64_encode('xyzxyz') is Hash that is needed to connection.

Any advice how to consume this service in C# .NET??

edit: Screens from IE:
[image: IE1]
[image: IE2]
[image: IE3]

edit: Save file on disk and add to visual studio (there are also my 2 other wcf service)
[image]

Comment: Can you browse the WSDL in a navigator ?

Comment: I edited my question and added some screenshots from WSDL, that I see in a IE navigator.

Comment: You can try to save the file on your local computer and make a reference to this file.

Comment: Done. And now what is the next step?

Comment: If so, you should have a client to call your web service. But be careful of having done a Service Reference (WCF) and not a Web reference. If so, you have a client for your web service.

Comment: Ok, I have my client, but when I look by fiddler at soap, that it is generated by my client, it is diferent that is it in 'example' one. In visual studio, when I use client.getParcel  I get "Query fault" :/

Comment: Do you know how to activate the traces on your client ? Do you have any logs on the PHP side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should browse the WSDL in your favorite navigator. The save the file on your local compouter.

Step 2, you must make a **Service Reference** to this file. It will normally create a client (WCF) to your PHP web service in your project.

Last step, you only have to instanciate a client in WCF.

Comment: I connect to that service, and send request, but when I get response now I have "You can not assign an object of type System.Int32 to an object of type System.Int32 []"  Stacktrace: System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, XmlSerializer serializer, MessagePartDescription returnPart, MessagePartDescriptionCollectio...

Comment: The WSDL seems to be a little weird. There is always a minOccurs to 1 and a maxOccurs to unbounded. In the reference.cs file (under the service reference directory, if you show all files, you will be able to see this file), you should have the description of each field, and each field should be declared as an array. Is there a way to correct/update the WSDL file of the PHP file ? If not, you can manually change the type of each field.

Comment: No, there is no way, to update PHP WSDL file, but I make it in another way. I change my proxy class return type to object, and it give me a XmlNode[], and now, I'm writning my own xml->myClass parser, to get information that I need from that web service. Thx for help.